# Save user's locations in MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, geolocation

I'm writing a REST API server in Node.js.
I need to store user's location (android app) in MySQL DB, and I would like to know what is the best way to do it.
I have users table that contains the following information:

```
user_id - VARCHAR(50)
email - VARCHAR(50)
phone_number - VARCHAR(50)
```

Is it right to store the geo location in that table? The table will conatin:

```
user_id - VARCHAR(50)
email - VARCHAR(50)
phone_number - VARCHAR(50)
longitude - float
latitude - float
```

My goal is that every time the user will click a specific buttons, I would like to update his location. Should I add another row to this table every time, or just update the existing row?
Should I save his locations in different table? Is there a meaning to save all his historic locations?

Comment: don't ever use float for anything.  I'd use decimal(9,6)

Comment: we can't tell you if there is a meaning to saving historic locations; that's something only whoever is using this data is going to know.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think I should store the geo location in same users table?